# Webpacker in Rails Project using angular cannot import .html.erb and .css from external template

Tags: angular, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I am using angular 4 for my project. I want to keep my `html.erb` and `.css` files separate from js files. I tried the following in my `component.ts` file. I did some configuration to load external html using the webpacker docs. But it is not letting me import `.html.erb` file. As well as the css file cannot be loaded. I also tried to load sass file but not working.

```
import templateString from './templatestring.html.erb';
import styles from './styles.css';
```

And in my component class:

```
templateUrl: templateString,
styleUrls: ['./style.css']
```

And this is giving the error and not working.

Please tell me how to fix this issue, I don't want to use inline template and stylesheet.

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution for that ?
I already get the solution of Manish Kongari, but it allow me only to load .html files, not .html.erb
I tried the rails-erb-loader ... but it seems that it expect js content for .js.erb, so when it loads my .html.erb ... syntax error :D
Did you find something else to try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly check this https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/typescript.md#html-templates-with-typescript-and-angular

```
yarn add html-loader
```

Add html-loader to config/webpack/environment.js

```
environment.loaders.set('html', {
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: false,
      caseSensitive: true,
      customAttrSurround: [ [/#/, /(?:)/], [/\*/, /(?:)/], [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/] ],
      customAttrAssign: [ /\)?\]?=/ ]
    }
  }]
})
```

Add .html to config/webpacker.yml

```
  extensions:
    - .elm
    - .coffee
    - .html
```

Setup a custom d.ts definition
// app/javascript/hello_angular/html.d.ts

```
declare module "*.html" {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

Add a template.html file relative to app.component.ts

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
Import template into app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import templateString from './template.html'

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-angular',
  template: templateString
})

export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular!'
}
```

Comment: This solution allow to load .html template, but does not load .html.erb does it ?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of css, you commented on the same issue in webpakcer rpeo. https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/963

declare a  module

```
declare module "*.css" {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

update `style` loader in webpacker

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

environment.loaders.set('style', {
    test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "to-string-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "css-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "postcss-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "resolve-url-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader"
    }]
})

module.exports = environment
```

import css

app/javascript/hello_angular/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import styleString from './app.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-angular',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
  styles:[styleString]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular!';
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer that's on the github issue, but it doesn't work for me. I added a comment there, please see: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/963#issuecomment-370253068