# Rails Webpacker : rails-erb-loader failing parsing .html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, erb, webpacker

I try to use the rails-erb-loader.

In my home.component.ts

```
import templateString from './home.component.html';
```

I have a home.component.html.erb

```
<div class="row">...</div>
```

I also have a app/javascript/packs/hello_erb.js.erb that was generated by the rake webpacker:install:erb

I get the following error :

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/hello_erb.js.erb
Module build failed: Error: rails-erb-loader failed with code: 1
```

I guess it's a configuration error loading the ruby bin, I guess I can fix this, my real problem is the following error :

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/hello_angular/app/home/home.component.html.erb
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
```

Straight forward my config :

config/webpack/loaders/erb.js

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.erb$/,
  enforce: 'pre',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'rails-erb-loader',
    options: {
      runner: (/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'ruby ' : '') + 'bin/rails runner'
    }
  }]
}
```

config/webpack/environment.js

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const typescript =  require('./loaders/typescript')
environment.loaders.append('typescript', typescript)

const html = require('./loaders/html')
environment.loaders.append('html', html)

const erb =  require('./loaders/erb')
environment.loaders.append('erb', erb)

module.exports = environment
```

And I have the `.erb` extension enabled in the config/webpacker.yml

My intuition is that my `.html.erb` is parsed as a javascript for some reason ... I have no idea why.

I digged into the `webpacker` and `rails_erb_loader` issues without success.
Any idea ?

BTW, I saw this similar question :
[Webpacker in Rails Project using angular cannot import .html.erb and .css from external template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002691/webpacker-in-rails-project-using-angular-cannot-import-html-erb-and-css-from-e/46639271#comment86407590_46639271)

Answer (score 2):

Also, webpacker provides erb loader if you execute:

```
rails webpacker:install:erb
```

Comment: It's been a while now I've handled this.
As far as I remember ... My problem with this one was it targeted only `.js.erb`and not `.html.erb`.
But to check really, may be I was also just miss using it ...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar bug and fixed it by adding the following in config/webpacker.rb:

```
default:
  extensions:
    - .js.erb # first array entry
```

And replacing `append` with `prepend` for erb in config/webpacker/environments.js:

```
environment.loaders.prepend('erb', erb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that's dead simple in the end ...

I created a loader definition html_erb.js

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.html.erb$/,
  loader: [
    'rails-erb-loader',
    'html-loader'
  ]
};
```

And that's it, it catch prior to the classic erb loader and transform the outup into html ...
That was what I was hoping the rails-erb-loader would do right of the box but ...

Anyway, it works :D

Comment: So why was `html.erb$` important when `.erb` should have matched as well?  Was it indeed pickup up your `.js.erb` files?

Comment: Good question, I removed the `.js.erb` that I spoke of above.
Templating js with ruby via `.js.erb` feels strange to me, just personal taste.
So there is no such things in my project.
Cannot help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this may help someone in the future: We had this error because our Ruby was incorrect and wouldn't compile.

Tried everything with configurations, got deep into Webpack(er) internals. In the end, our variable name was typed incorrectly in our erb file.